# comparing integers in c

Tags: c, arrays, strcmp

I have a problem comparing integers. I know that in C you can compare string using strcmp. I am looking for a way to compare integers in an array. I found an example online but it compares strings. I can seem to find a way to changed into integers

I was wondering if I can get some help changing the code below to compare integers.

```
 char sname[30]; int  i;

printf("Please enter the class numbers:\n");
scanf("%s", &sname);        
for (i = 0; i<tail; i++)
    if (strcmp(sname, classschedule[i].classNumber) == 0) 
    {           
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: What is `classschedule`?

Comment: You compare integers using the comparison operators, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `!=`, and `==`.

Comment: ...  but userX is reading a string!

Comment: @EdHeal: Yes, but according to the question, he wants some help changing his code to make it an integer. Easy problem to solve!

Comment: If this were C++, then you could use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare. Just sayin'

Answer (score 3):

Making an assumption `classschedule[i].classNumber` is an `int`

```
int  sname; int  i;

printf("Please enter the class numbers:\n");
scanf("%d", &sname); /* Should check the return value here! */       
for (i = 0; i<tail; i++) { /*Always put on the braces - otherwise it is embarrassing when your trousers fall down*/
    if (sname == classschedule[i].classNumber) 
    {           
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For just a simple integer, you can use the standard comparison operators (<, <=, >, >=, ==). For an array of integers, you can define your own comparison function:

```
 int CompareIntegerArrays(int* a0, int len0, int* a1, int len1)
 {
    int minlen = min(len0, len1);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < minlen; ++i) {
       int diff = a0[i] - a1[i];
       if (diff != 0) {
         return diff;
       }
    }
    return len0 - len1;
 }
```

Comment: Why the subtraction when a comparison would suffice?

Comment: @EdHeal, this is what `strcmp` and `memcmp` do, they return a value that is negative, zero, or positive depending upon whether the first argument is less-than, equal-to, or greater-than the second.

Comment: @pat - If you refer to the original post all is required is equality (or lack of). So for the question in hand one does not need to be more complex than that

Comment: @EdHeal, the question is somewhat ambiguous. It is not clear if the OP is asking for a way to find a specific integer in an array, or if they are asking to compare arrays of integers as if they were strings.  The former is what your answer is showing, and the latter is what this one is showing.  I'll concede that your answer is the one for the question that makes the most sense!

Comment: @EdHeal the subtraction is a simplification; I could use a direct comparison, but then I would need two cases (one for greater and one for less) instead of one for unequal.

Answer (score 0):

The various string comparison functions in the Standard C Library work because the end of the string is indicated by a special character, a binary zero.  So the various functions basically do an element by element comparison until the end of one of the strings is reached.

So for instance a strcpy() function may be written like:

```
char * strcpy (char *dest, char *src)
{
   int i = 0;
   while (dest[i] = src[i]) i++;  // copy a char from src to dest until zero found.
   return dest;
}
```

For integer arrays you can not really depend on a special character indicating the end of the array since any integer value could be a valid array element value so you have to know the length of the arrays.

```
int  iarray1[30], iarray2[30];

//  ...  values are put into the two arrays

int i;
bool bSame = true;
for (i = 0, bSame=true; bSame && i < 30; i++) bSame = bSame && (iarray1[i] == iarray2[i]);
```

You might want to have a function that would do the comparison such as:

```
bool IntArrayCmp (int *ia1, int *ia2, size_t ncount)
{
    bool  bSame = true;
    size_t nindex = 0;
    for (nindex = 0, bSame = true; bSame && nindex < ncount; nindex++) bSame = bSame && (ia1[nindex] == ia1[nindex]);
    return bSame;
}
```

The question that next arises is what about arrays that are not the same length and whether the comparison function should require the length of each of the arrays allowing the function to determine if both integer arrays have the same number of elements as part of deciding if the two functions are equivalent or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
You cannot use strcmp for Integers as it is only used for strings
Try This Code-->

char sname[30]; int  i;
printf("Please enter the class numbers:\n");
scanf("%s", &sname);        
for (i = 0; i<tail; i++)
{
   if (sname == classschedule[i].classNumber) 
  {           
    return i;
  }
}

This should work
```